# React router with redux multiple component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

```
Following are the details for code snippet. 

<Provider store={store}> 
<MuiThemeProvider theme={customTheme}> 
<Loader /> 
<Router> 
<Switch> 
<Route path="/" component={Layout} /> 
</Switch> 
</Router> 
</MuiThemeProvider> 
</Provider>
```

- Here I want to call login component before this Layout and into the
  Login component when user click on login then it should go into this
  layout.
                This layout component contains various routes with some common component like 
       header
       sidebar
        rightsidebar
       {layout routes around 7 to 8 routes}
       footer
       so Here all the component render with the common header sidebar rightsidebar 
       and footer , but only login component does not contains
        the all the common header.. as mentioned above.so requirement is first to load login component and click on login should render
  component from layout specified by the routes.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you make pages to extend the layout component?In that case the Login component would render the layout component and manipulate the display of the header component through the props.You can set default props to the layout to match most of you subpages.

**Layout**

```
const Layout = props => (

  <div className="layout-container">

   {props.displayCommonHeader && <CommonHeaderComponent />}

   {props.children}

  </div>

)
```

**Login**

```
const Login = props => (

  <Layout displayCommonHeader={false}>
   <MyCustomLoginFormComponent />
  </Layout>

)
```

**SomeSubpage**

```
const SomeSubpage = props => (
 <Layout displayCommonHeader={true}>
  Custom Stuff
 </Layout>
)
```

I hope it helps!Good luck!